# php file to delete all images with a specfic string

Tags: php, wordpress

i need a php script that can delete all files in a folder and subfolders than contain a "-" in them. The file are images- specifically duplicate thumbnails of images in wordpress media library

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried something for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let the structure is

```
/images
    - /list1
        image-11.jpeg
        image-12.jpeg
    - /list2
        image-21.jpeg
        image-22.jpeg
```

using RecursiveDirectoryIterator we can delete all the images.

```
    $parentDirPath = "images";//pathtofolder
    if (is_dir($parentDirPath)) {
        $directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($parentDirPath);
        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory) as $fileNetPath => $file) {
            if ($file->isFile()) {
                $fileName = $file->getFilename();
                if (preg_match("/-/", $fileName)) {//checking for matching names
                    echo "<br/> Deleting file : ".$fileNetPath;
                    @unlink($fileNetPath);                
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: how would i go about actually running it online?

Comment: create a sample folder structure as yours in your local and try the script. Make sure it is working according to your requirement. Then try with your original folder. Give the full path to the folder for $parentDirPath

Comment: do i need special command to run it or do i just upload the file to the images folder and visit the file via link?

Comment: As it is deleting the file, make sure it is not deleting any needed items. You can upload the php script by commenting deleting and displaying the filename

{echo $fileNetPath."<br/>";//@unlink($fileNetPath);}

If working fine un comment the deletion and run the script again

Comment: excellent was able to get it to work.. how can I make it display results e.g deleting file.. thanks!

Comment: i figured it out but thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$dir = "img";//folder url which consist file to delete. you can use     wordpress file location using wordpress function 
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
  if (strpos($filename,'_') !== false)//check whether it conist of '_'
  {
   unlink('img/'.$filename);//remove file from folder
  }   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `unlink()` to delete the files and `strpos()` to check if `-` is present in the file name.

```
$dup_thumb = glob('path to folder');
foreach($dup_thumb as $duplicate){ 
if(is_file($duplicate) && strpos($duplicate,'-') !== false)
     unlink($duplicate);
}
```

Comment: will it delete only those files which path I put in code? Or it will delete all files from root as well?

Comment: only the path which is specified.

Comment: how would  i go about running this on my website?